# undefined method `creation_time' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i am getting this error

> undefined method `creation_time' for nil:NilClass

here is what i have

```
last_request_timestamp = (
  FakeOrder.where("creation_time <= ?",current_time_second)
           .order(:creation_time).last ||
  FakeOrder.order(:creation_time).last).creation_time
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @RohitYadav Do you have any records in your table?  Using RAILS console, check the values returned by both expressions - it seems both are returning `nil`

Comment: @RohitYadav break the problem down into smaller chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both queries return `nil` when there are no `FakeOrders` in the database. In that case

```
FakeOrder.where("creation_time <= ?",current_time_second)
         .order(:creation_time).last ||
  FakeOrder.order(:creation_time).last
```

will return `nil` and calling `creation_time` on `nil` leads to the error.

A simple approach to solve this problem might be to simply return `nil` in that case:

```
last_request_timestamp = (
  FakeOrder.where("creation_time <= ?",current_time_second)
           .order(:creation_time).last ||
  FakeOrder.order(:creation_time).last
).try(:creation_time)
```

Comment: Can I just ask what a FakeQuery is? I've never heard of it before

Comment: @RichPeck : Ups, Typo, I  meant `FaceOrder`. Fixed my answer.

Comment: Okay thanks! I thought it was some SQL wizardry or something